# Want to prompt browser to save csv

Tags: python, pyramid

Want to prompt browser to save csv using pyramid.response.Response searched for clues and found here's [a link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-csv/?from=olddocs) Django answer but i can't use it with Pyramid wsgi my code looks like this:

```
from pyramid.response import Response
def get_list_names_emails(request):
    session, env = request.db, request.client_env
    response = Response(content_type='text/csv')
    output = StringIO()
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerow(['SomeName', 'SomeEmail', 'CompanyName])
    csv_output = output.getvalue()
    return csv_output
```

Answer (score 15):

As a cleaner way to do that, you can register a renderer.

In your configuration set-up, add:

```
    config.add_renderer(name='csv',
                        factory='mypackage.renderers.CSVRenderer')
```

then in `mypackage/renderers.py`:

```
class CSVRenderer(object):
    def __init__(self, info):
        pass

    def __call__(self, value, system):
        fout = StringIO.StringIO()
        writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

        writer.writerow(value['header'])
        writer.writerows(value['rows'])

        resp = system['request'].response
        resp.content_type = 'text/csv'
        resp.content_disposition = 'attachment;filename="report.csv"'
        return fout.getvalue()
```

After that, you can decorate your view with the renderer:

```
@view_config(..., renderer='csv')
def myview(self):
    header = ['name', 'surname', 'address']

    rows = [
            (
                row['name'],
                row['surname'],
                row['address'],
            )
        for row in query_rows(.....)
        ]

    return {
            'header': header,
            'rows': rows
            }
```

The advantage of this approach is better testable view code (you just check for the dictionary values, no need to parse anything) and you can also add a XLS or whatever renderer to the same view:

```
@view_config(..., renderer='xls')
@view_config(..., renderer='csv')
def myview(self):
    ...
```

Answer (score 9):

Try adding Content-Disposition:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.csv"'
```

Answer (score 3):

It's better to set content type as well

```
response['Content-type'] = 'text/csv'
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.csv"'
```

Comment: Isn't it what OP's code already does in response = Response(content_type='text/csv')?

Comment: Mine didn't work without this.  It would show a download dialog with all my info, but say I was downloading a HTML file.