# export list to csv and present to user via browser

Tags: python, pyramid

[Want to prompt browser to save csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973921/want-to-prompt-browser-to-save-csv)

^^working off above question, file is exporting correctly but the data is not displaying correctly.

```
@view_config(route_name='csvfile', renderer='csv')
def csv(self):
name = DBSession.query(table).join(othertable).filter(othertable.id == 9701).all()
header = ['name']
rows = []
for item in name:
    rows = [item.id]
return {
    'header': header,
    'rows': rows
}
```

Getting `_csv.Error
Error: sequence expected` but if I change in my renderer `writer.writerows(value['rows'])` to `writer.writerow(value['rows'])` the file will download via the browser just fine. Problem is, it's not displaying data in each row. The entire result/dataset is in one row, so each entry is in it's own column rather than it's own row.

Comment: What about `name.table['name']` ?

Comment: Still can't figure this out if anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. kept getting `Error: sequence expected` so I was looking at the output. Decided to try putting the result inside another list.

```
@view_config(route_name='csv', renderer='csv')
def csv(self):
    d = datetime.now()
    query = DBSession.query(table, othertable).join(othertable).join(thirdtable).filter(
        thirdtable.sid == 9701)
    header = ['First Name', 'Last Name']
    rows = []
    filename = "csvreport" + d.strftime(" %m/%d").replace(' 0', '')
    for i in query:
        items = [i.table.first_name, i.table.last_name, i.othertable.login_time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"),
    ]
    rows.append(items)
    return {
        'header': header,
        'rows': rows,
        'filename': filename
    }
```

This accomplishes 3 things. Fills out the header, fills the rows, and passes through a filename.

Renderer should look like this:

```
class CSVRenderer(object):
    def __init__(self, info):
        pass

    def __call__(self, value, system):
        fout = StringIO.StringIO()
        writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=',',quotechar =',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

        writer.writerow(value['header'])
        writer.writerows(value['rows'])

        resp = system['request'].response
        resp.content_type = 'text/csv'
        resp.content_disposition = 'attachment;filename='+value['filename']+'.csv'
        return fout.getvalue()
```

This way, you can use the same csv renderer anywhere else and be able to pass through your own filename. It's also the only way I could figure out how to get the data from one column in the database to iterate through one column in the renderer. It feels a bit hacky but it works and works well.

Answer (score 0):

First, I wonder if having a `return` statement inside your `for` loop isn't also causing problems; from the linked example it looks like their loop was in the prior statement.

I think what it looks like it's doing is it's building a collection of rows based on "table" having columns with the same name as the headers.  What are the fields in your `table` table?

```
name = DBSession.query(table).join(othertable).filter(othertable.id == 9701).all()
```

This is going to give you back essentially a collection of rows from `table`, as if you did a SELECT query on it.

Something like

```
name = DBSession.query(table).join(othertable).filter(othertable.id == 9701).all()
header = ['name']
rows = []

for item in name:
  rows.append(item.name)

return {
        'header': header,
        'rows': r
        }
```

Comment: Getting an error, `TypeError: writerows() argument must be iterable`. Seems its complaining on `writer.writerows(value['rows'])`

Comment: Seems I wasn't returning the right thing. Now getting `_csv.Error Error: sequence expected`

Comment: K, so I changed `writer.writerows(value['rows'])` to `writer.writerow(value['rows'])` and it gives me a CSV. It wrote  the entire result in one row, instead of one entry for one row. Probably because of my change to `writerow()` Not sure how to get this formatted correctly since it throws an error with `writerows()`

Comment: Adjusted my question to better reflect the problem.